# doesn't symbolic link changes it's permissions if I remove permissions in actual file?

Tags: permissions, symlink

I actually started learning Unix and while doing so I stuck here. Though It may seem silly question I'm actually unclear with it so please help me.

I've a file as somefile.txt and a symbolic link which refers to `somefile.txt`,
and I found default permissions for both are `rw-r--r--`.

When I change permissions of `somefile.txt` (`chmod ugo=rwx somefile.txt`), I found a change in both files as `rwxrwxrwx`. But again when I try to change permissions by giving `chmod u-rx somefile.txt`, I found change only in `somefile.txt` but not in symbolic link. I wonder why? I'm using RedHat cygwin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have mistaken the output of at least one command. The permissions of a symbolic link are always `rwxrwxrwx`, or rather they don't have permissions at all:

```
$ touch file
$ ls -l 
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 muru muru 0 Dec  5 20:53 file
$ ln -s file link
$ ls -l 
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 muru muru 0 Dec  5 20:53 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru 4 Dec  5 20:53 link -> file
$ chmod a+x file
$ ls -l
total 0
-rwxrwxr-x 1 muru muru 0 Dec  5 20:53 file
lrwxrwxrwx 1 muru muru 4 Dec  5 20:53 link -> file
```

See this [FreeBSD FAQ](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/faq/misc.html#idp60614560) for more information.

And since you're on Linux, [`man chmod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/chmod.1.html) says:

```
   chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system
   call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since  the
   permissions  of  symbolic  links  are  never  used.   However, for each
   symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions
   of  the  pointed-to  file.   In  contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links
   encountered during recursive directory traversals.
```

Comment: My bad. I've make a mistake without my proper attention. Thank you so much for this help.